# Copy short 8.3 filename in long mode (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-processing, short-filenames

Trying to copy from command line a file named "SCOOTE~1.txt" to a folder where there is a file called "Scooter -  Cosmos.txt".

The problem is that copy will contract the name of "Scooter -  Cosmos.txt" to "Scoote~1.txt" as well and will ask if I want to overwrite that file.

How can I literally copy the "SCOOTE~1.txt" without affecting other long-named files ? Suggestion of external command-line tools is accepted.

Comment: You can change the short name with `fsutil file setshortname "Scooter - Cosmos.txt" SCOOTE~2.TXT`. Otherwise you'll have to copy "SCOOTE~1.txt" to a different name.

Comment: Original file names must be kept. They do not conflict anyway.

Comment: The short name is just another name for the file in the directory. It's a lot like a hard link. So the existing names *do conflict*.

Comment: @Eryksun's solution will alter the _short_ name of the `Scooter - Cosmos.txt` file so it no longer clashes with the short/only name of the `SCOOTE~1.txt` file. The _normally-visible_ names of both will remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

### Recreation of Problem

```
c:\Test> > "Scooter - Cosmos.txt" echo File with long name
c:\Test> md SFN
c:\Test> > "SFN\SCOOTE~1.TXT" echo File with short name
c:\Test> dir/s/x
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BE3C-8BC1

 Directory of c:\Test

22/09/2017  08:51    <DIR>                       .
22/09/2017  08:51    <DIR>                       ..
22/09/2017  08:50                21 SCOOTE~1.TXT Scooter - Cosmos.txt
22/09/2017  08:51    <DIR>                       Test
               1 File(s)             21 bytes

 Directory of c:\Test\SFN

22/09/2017  08:51    <DIR>                       .
22/09/2017  08:51    <DIR>                       ..
22/09/2017  08:51                22              SCOOTE~1.TXT
               1 File(s)             22 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               2 File(s)             43 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  104,170,942,464 bytes free
```

Here the current directory has a file with a *long-name* of `Scooter - Cosmos.txt` and a *short-name* of `SCOOTE~1.TXT` (*Note*: the short-name is *already* in place at this stage). Also, the directory `SFN` contains a file called `SCOOTE~1.TXT` – because this name "fits" in the 8.3 format, it does not have a separate short-name.

If we now try to copy this file into the current directory, because the short-/only name of the file being copied matches the short-name of the file already present, it prompts about overwriting:

```
c:\Test> copy "SFN\SCOOTE~1.TXT"
Overwrite c:\Test\SCOOTE~1.TXT? (Yes/No/All): n
        0 file(s) copied.
```

### Single-Instance Fix

As *eryksun* suggested, you can use the `fsutil file setshortname` command to fix one-off clashes by changing the *short-name* of the file in the current directory:

```
c:\Test> fsutil file setshortname "Scooter - Cosmos.txt" SCOOTE~2.TXT

c:\Test> dir/x
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BE3C-8BC1

 Directory of c:\Test

22/09/2017  09:09    <DIR>                       .
22/09/2017  09:09    <DIR>                       ..
22/09/2017  08:50                21 SCOOTE~2.TXT Scooter - Cosmos.txt
22/09/2017  08:51    <DIR>                       SFN
               1 File(s)             21 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  104,168,501,248 bytes free

c:\Test> copy "SFN\SCOOTE~1.TXT"
        1 file(s) copied.

c:\Test> dir/x
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BE3C-8BC1

 Directory of c:\Test

22/09/2017  09:09    <DIR>                       .
22/09/2017  09:09    <DIR>                       ..
22/09/2017  08:50                21 SCOOTE~2.TXT Scooter - Cosmos.txt
22/09/2017  08:51                22              SCOOTE~1.TXT
22/09/2017  08:51    <DIR>                       SFN
               2 File(s)             43 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  104,168,464,384 bytes free
```

Here we can see that the short-name of `Scooter - Cosmos.txt` has been changed so that it no longer clashes with `SCOOTE~1.TXT`; the copy proceeds with no warning and both files sit side-by-side in the current directory.

### Multiple-Instance Fix

If there are (or could be) several clashes with the files in the target directory, an alternative approach is to use the `fsutil 8dot3name strip` command to *remove* the 8.3-format short-names from all files at once:

```
c:\Test> fsutil 8dot3name strip .
Scanning registry...

Total affected registry keys:                   0

Stripping 8dot3 names...

Total files and directories scanned:            2
Total 8dot3 names found:                        1
Total 8dot3 names stripped:                     1

For details on the operations performed please see the log:
  "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\8dot3_removal_log @(GMT 2017-09-22 08-36-00).log"

c:\Test> dir/x
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BE3C-8BC1

 Directory of c:\Test

22/09/2017  09:36    <DIR>                       .
22/09/2017  09:36    <DIR>                       ..
22/09/2017  08:50                21              Scooter - Cosmos.txt
22/09/2017  09:33    <DIR>                       SFN
               1 File(s)             21 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  104,154,349,568 bytes free
```

As can be seen, the file `Scooter - Cosmos.txt` no longer has a short-name, so there is no clash when `SCOOTE~1.TXT` is copied into the current directory:

```
c:\Test> copy "SFN\SCOOTE~1.TXT"
        1 file(s) copied.

c:\Test> dir/x
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BE3C-8BC1

 Directory of c:\Test

22/09/2017  09:40    <DIR>                       .
22/09/2017  09:40    <DIR>                       ..
22/09/2017  08:50                21              Scooter - Cosmos.txt
22/09/2017  08:51                22              SCOOTE~1.TXT
22/09/2017  09:33    <DIR>                       SFN
               2 File(s)             43 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  104,151,703,552 bytes free
```

**NOTE**: The first stage of this command – `Scanning registry...` – may take some time as it is looking through the registry for references to the 8.3-format names that are about to be removed. See `fsutil 8dot3name strip /?` for more details of this command.

### Caution (*Applies to both methods*)

As the help from the `fsutil 8dot3name strip /?` command says:

> This command permanently removes 8dot3 file names from your volume. It
>   will list the registry keys pointing to the stripped 8dot3names but
>   will not modify the affected registry keys. Stripping will not be
>   performed on files with full path names longer than the maximum path
>   length of 260 characters.

both these commands modify (or remove) the 8.3-format names of selected files. If you have any references to the files concerned (either in the registry, configuration files, or elsewhere in `.BAT` files etc.) then these references will no longer be valid. *Use either solution with due caution*.

Comment: Beware of the LFN 260+ issue around `fsutil 8dotname strip ...` command, as long as it can not access the LFN 260+ paths the same way as others at least on Windows 8. So either you use LFN+SFN or the LFN only. Attempt to strip LFNs files and folders from already created SFNs is a half working solution.